# How to hide 'add to cart' button on content type full view?

Tags: 7, commerce

How to hide '**add to cart**' button, on full mode view of a specific content type?
It has to be done on condition if product is purchased for this content type.

I tried to add custom field template but for add to cart button could not find the right template name. I also found out the field name which displays add to cart "field-product-ref" but the template field--field-product-ref.tpl.php is not working.
Need help in either identifying correct template name or any other approach which is correct?

Comment: Are you using ubercart or ?

Comment: drupal commerce on D7

Comment: Hiding the add to cart form is easy (e.g hide in "Manage Display"), the hard part will be determining if the current user has bought a product referenced on that product display and hiding it dynamically.

Comment: yes I agree... for "hard part" now I am exploring making use of "<themeName>_theme_form_alter". And awaiting sound advices.

Comment: There is some information on this in https://drupal.org/node/1266132 where you implement hook_form_alter for the add to cart form.

Answer (score 0):

You could use devel_themer module. After enable the module, a checkbox appear on left bottom of the window then, select the checkbox now you could find the template name after click the add to cart button...

Answer (score 0):

I manage to resolve it.
Now sharing back with the community.

**To hide the add-to-cart button on FULL view mode if product is purchased**

```
 1. Implement this solution in _theme_form_alter.
 2. Sql query to check if product id belongs to complete order list for particular user
     "$query = db_select('commerce_order', 'cord');
    $query->join('commerce_line_item', 'li', 'cord.order_id = li.order_id');
    $query->join('field_data_commerce_product', 'prod', 'li.line_item_id = prod.entity_id');
    $query->condition('cord.uid', $user->uid, '=')
          ->condition('cord.status', 'completed', '=')
          ->condition('commerce_product_product_id ',$prod_id,'=')
          ->fields('prod', array('commerce_product_product_id'));
    $result = $query->execute();
    $resultValue = $result->fetchColumn(0);"
 3. Hide add-to-cart button if product id matches query result
```